# Python 3 CouchDB single update vs batch

Tags: python, mysql, insert, couchdb, bulk

This is my first post :) so I'll apologize beforehand.  I'm working on exporting data from mysql to couchdb, when an item has been saved, i mark the mysql item with a recently updated date.  Below I have a python function which takes in a json object one by one and some random id to update on mysql locally:

```
def write_json_to_couchdb(json_obj, id):
    #couchdb auto create doc_id and rev
    doc_id = ''
    revision_or_exception = ''
    for (success, doc_id, revision_or_exception) in db.update(json_obj):
        print(success, doc_id, revision_or_exception)
        # mark id inside mysql db, so we know its been saved to couchdb
        mysql.update_item_date(id)
```

This solution above works but is quite slow, both writing to couchdb and updating onto mysql, how can I use "bulk api" or "batch api", without using curl.    I believe couchdb's db.update(item) can also take a list like this db.update(dict_of_items).  How can i specify "batch ok".  Are there any other method i'm unaware of.  Seems there's few examples online.

Would this increase speed significantly?  Also how can i specify the "batch size" of lets say 1000 records.

Here's what I'm thinking a better solution would be:

```
def write_json_to_couchdb_bulk(json_obj_list, id_list):
    doc_id = ''
    revision_or_exception = ''
    for (success, doc_id, revision_or_exception) in db.update(json_obj_list):
        print(success, doc_id, revision_or_exception)
        # update added_date with current datetime

    for id in id_list:
        mysql.update_item_date(id)
```

Thanks,

SW

Answer (score 0):

```
import couchdb
from couchdb import *

def write_json_to_couchdb_bulk(json_obj_list):
    for doc in db.update(json_obj_list):
        print(repr(doc))

json_obj_list = [
    Document(type='Person', name='John Doe'),
    Document(type='Person', name='Mary Jane'),
    Document(type='City', name='Gotham City')
]
write_json_to_couchdb_bulk(json_obj_list)
```

Here's the solution I came up with, its much faster.